# Cache js/css resources for my project to work offline

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, caching, cdn

I have been given a project (web application) to work, which depends on many online js/css resources (e.g. jquery `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`)

There are a lot of them in my html templates in various places. Is there any way (even a firefox plugin) that would let me download them (or cache them locally, in some way) so I can work offline?

I have to be away in a place without internet access and I have to take my laptop with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Basket.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/basket.js):

> a script and resource loader for caching and loading scripts using localStorage

It can also cache CSS.

Example:

```
basket
    .require({ url: 'missing.js' })
    .then(function () {
        // Success
    }, function (error) {
        // There was an error fetching the script
        console.log(error);
    });
```